# Lorentz transformation and causality of the Dirac field

Tags: dirac-equation, causality, lorentz-symmetry

Consider the Dirac quantum field $$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\mathbb{p}}}} \sum_{s} [a^{s}_{\mathbb{p}}u^{s}(\mathbb{p})e^{-\mathrm{i}p \cdot x} + b^{s\dagger}_{\mathbb{p}}v^{s}(\mathbb{p})e^{+\mathrm{i}p \cdot x}],$$ using the conventions of Peskin and Schroeder. Due to the anticommutation relations $$\{a^{r}_{\mathbb{p}},a^{s\dagger}_{\mathbb{q}} \} = (2\pi)^{3}\delta^{(3)}(\mathbb{p}-\mathbb{q})\delta^{rs}, \\ \{b^{r\dagger}_{\mathbb{p}},b^{s\dagger}_{\mathbb{q}} \} = (2\pi)^{3}\delta^{(3)}(\mathbb{p}-\mathbb{q})\delta^{rs},$$ all other anticommutators being zero; and the spin sums $$\sum_{s} u^{s}(\mathbb{p})u^{s\dagger}(\mathbb{p}) = (\gamma^{\rho} p_{\rho} + m) \gamma^{0}, \\ \sum_{s} v^{s}(\mathbb{p})v^{s\dagger}(\mathbb{p}) = (\gamma^{\rho} p_{\rho} - m) \gamma^{0},$$ it obeys $$\{ \psi_{a}(x),\psi^{\dagger}_{b}(y) \} = [(\mathrm{i}\gamma^{\rho}\partial_{\rho\vert x} + m)\gamma^{0}]_{ab} \Delta(x-y),$$ where $\partial_{\rho\vert x}$ means differentiation with respect to $x$, and where $$\Delta(x-y) = \int \frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{2E_{\mathbb{p}}}[e^{-\mathrm{i}p \cdot (x-y)} - e^{+\mathrm{i}p \cdot (x-y)}].$$ This implies causality: $\{ \psi_{a}(x),\psi^{\dagger}_{b}(y) \} = 0$, for $x-y$ space-like, because $\Delta(x-y) = 0$ then.

Consider next the Lorentz transformation $\psi'(x) = \Lambda_{1/2}\psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$. As with other transformations, it induces transformations of the creation and annihilation operators, respectively, i.e., it may equivalently be performed by transformations of these operators alone. These transformations, the explicit forms of which are not important here, preserve the anticommutation relations, of course.

Now for my question: Why can a transformation of only the annihilation operators $a^{s}_{\mathbb{p}}$, say, i.e., the positive frequency part of $\psi(x)$, **not** be performed? Although such a transformation does not 'back-induce' a transformation of $\psi(x)$ itself as *any matrix times* $\psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)$, as is the case for the 'full' Lorentz transformation, it will still preserve the anticommutation relations for the creation and annihilation operators and thus imply a causal theory.

A related question is the following: Why must, as all text books seem to claim, any symmetry transformation of $\psi(x)$ yield something equal to *some matrix times* $\psi$, evaluated either at the same spacetime point (for internal transformations like $U(1)$ transformations, and charge conjugation), or at some other spacetime point (for external transformations like Lorentz transformations, parity conjugation, and time reversal)?

Comment: Your commutation rules are wrong: x and y have to be replaced for p and q...I am referring to the second and third formulas.

Comment: I do not understand well your first question. Are you saying, why don't considering objects like $\Psi(x) := \psi_+(x) + \Lambda_{1/2}\psi_-(\Lambda^{-1}x)$?  With obvious notation

Comment: We obviously can, however they have a bad behavior   under spacetime translations...

Comment: Regarding your second question, we are dealing here with the double nature of a field. On the one hand it is a classical object and thus isometries $g$ of the spacetime act on it $\psi \to \psi_g$ where $\psi_g(x) = L_g \psi(A_gx)$  for suitable transformations $L_g$ and $A_g$ represented by matrices and linear non-homogeneous transformations.

Comment: On the other hand we expect from Wigner theorem that there is a unitary representation $U_g$ of the spacetime isometry $g$ and that the action of $U_g$ on the operator $\psi$ is in agreement with the classical transformation: $U_g \psi(x) U^*_g = L_g \psi(A_gx)$

Comment: @Valter Moretti: Thanks a lot for these valuable inputs of yours. It has really given me something to ponder. And yes, what I had in mind was your $\Psi(x)$.